# How to make browser run module code first before normal text/javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

How to make sure the script tag run in the order I define and also synchronously, because in the module I will import some other module remotely, and then use it later.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script defer="false" async="false" type="module">
    // will have import some module remotely here as well
    console.log('one');
</script>

<script defer="false" async="false" type="text/javascript">
    console.log('two');
</script>

<script defer="false" async="false" type="module">
    console.log('three');
</script>

<script defer="false" async="false" type="text/javascript">
    console.log('four');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Console Output:

```
two
four
one
three
```

My finding is the engine will run all the vanilla script in order first then only run the module script in order. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Can't you just add `type="module"` to the second script?

Comment: Can't you just add the second script to a module as well you can import inside the first script? Since the second script probably has a dependency on the first.

Comment: @Reyno can't really, the second script tag actually can be many small script tags from different places, make it module will break different thing.